# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' vcf

Tags: python, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm writing a python code to modify a vcf file but I have an error that I haven't been able to fix for a few hours.

Here is the part of the code involved:

```
def liste_genes(variantsYN):
    retour=[]
    print variantsYN.split(";")[0]
    if variantsYN.split(";")[0] not in retour:
        retour.append(variantsYN.split(";")[0])

    return retour
```

the terminal output:

```
['1', '783071', 'rs142849724', 'C', 'T', '.', 'PASS', 'ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921', 'GT', 'C;', 'C;', 'T;|C;', 'C;', 'T;|C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;|T;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;|T;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;|T;', 'C;', 'C;', 'C;\n']
('chromosome', '1')
variantsYN : ['ENSG00000228794;ENST00000624927|ENST00000623808|ENST00000445118|ENST00000448975|ENST00000610067|ENST00000608189|ENST00000609139|ENST00000449005|ENST00000416570|ENST00000623070|ENST00000609009|ENST00000622921']
```

the returned error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alloscore2.py", line 476, in <module>
    creation_dico(dic_localisation_atlas,"vcf.vcf",Paris_Cohorte,"Paris",dico_transm_ensembl)
  File "alloscore2.py", line 333, in creation_dico
    liste_g=liste_genes(variantsYN)
  File "alloscore2.py", line 115, in liste_genes
    print variantsYN.split(";")[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: try `variantsYN[0]` instead of `variantsYN` . variantsYN is a list and you want to split the first element of this list

Comment: Thank you, you're absolutely right, it solves this first problem thank you very much

Comment: Could you tell what is the expected output of this function?

Comment: In my code, I read a vcf file line by line (variant by variant) and I want to retrieve for each variant (line) the corresponding gene and thus create a list containing all the genes in my file. so here, for this one line, I have : ['ENSG00000228794'], if I have 2 lines, I will have :  ['ENSG00000228794','ENSG1432780]